# Center Text in FlatList next to Icon - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I am currently trying to center the text from the FlatList.
By centering I mean I want it to be in the middle, right of each Icon.

Currently this is how is displaying, it's on the bottom. I just want it to be a little bit higher:[image]

Here is how my component looks like:
I have tried to implement few styles, but still no success.
The thing that crossed my mind but did not try was to hard code each line and drop the loop, but I am not sure if this is right to do.

```
import SocialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import BookingIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import FeatherIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';


export const bookIcon = (<BookingIcon name="pencil-square-o" size={40} color="purple" />);
export const calendarIcon = (<SocialIcon name="calendar" size={40} color="purple" />);
export const questionIcon = (<SocialIcon name="questioncircleo" size={40} color="purple" />);
export const externalLinkIcon = (<FeatherIcons name="external-link" size={40} color="purple" />);



class AboutMe extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: "About Me",
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.topBox}>
          <View style={styles.circleOuter} />
            <View style={styles.circle} />

          </View>
          <View style={styles.middleBox}>

          </View>
          <View style={styles.bottomBox}>
            <FlatList
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listItem}
              data={[
                {key: 'Book a free appointment', page:'Book', icon: bookIcon},
                {key: 'Availability', page:'Availability', icon:calendarIcon},
                {key: 'FAQ', page:'Faq', icon: questionIcon},
                {key: 'Useful Links', page: 'Links', icon: externalLinkIcon},
              ]}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Book')}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(`${item.page}`)}>
                      <Text >{item.icon}{item.key}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                  )
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    };
  };

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    topBox: {
      flex:3,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      justifyContent:'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    },
    middleBox: {
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    },
    bottomBox: {
      flex:4,
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      padding: 20

    },
    circle: {
      width: 160,
      height: 160,
      borderRadius: 160/2,
      backgroundColor: 'green',
      position: 'absolute'
  },
    circleOuter: {
      width: 180,
      height: 180,
      borderRadius: 180/2,
      backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
    listItem: {
      flex:1,
      justifyContent: 'center' 
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 20,
    }

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the Text tag in a `View/TouchableHighlight` tag and then center the text tag vertically. Try this and let me know. It could be necessary that you wrap the icons in a separated image tag. if the code avode dont work means that a separeted tag is necessary so let me know!

```
<TouchableHighlight  
  style={styles.buttonsStyle}
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(`${item.page}`)}
>
   <Text>{item.icon}{item.key}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
...
...
...
//in the styles add
buttonsStyle:{
  justifyContent: 'center',
}
```

**EDIT1**

In order to wrap the icons it should be like following.. Note that you cannot use `TouchableHighlight` in this case. it seems to be a bug with react-native. aslo i used `TouchableOpacity`

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity 
       style={styles.buttonsStyle} 
       onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(`${item.page}`)}
     >
       <Image style={styles.imgStyles} source={item.icon} />
       <Text style={styles.mappedTextStyle}>{item.key}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }}
```

styles to change/add

```
    buttonsStyle:{
      alignItems: 'center',
      flexDirection:'row',
      marginTop: 5, 
    },
    imgStyles:{
      width: 40, 
      height: 40, 
      marginRight: 10
    },
    mappedTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: 'black'
    },
```

**EDIT 2**

In order to cover vector-icons lib, i have created a Expo snack for producing the desired behavior. Expo snack has also the expected solution for the problem [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/centered-text)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it doesn't work. Maybe the whole approach is wrong in general?

Comment: @squeekyDave it is good. could yo tell me what the item.icon are? const?

Comment: @squeekyDave i just create a Expo snack.. you should do it like there.. upvote would be nice! [Expo link](https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/Y2VudG)

Comment: @squeekyDave if the link dont work, here the good one https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/centered-text

Comment: Yes it is a const and it doesn't work :/ The last link you have send looks really nice and it is exactly what I need it just does not want to render my icons.

Comment: @squeekyDave you have to wrap the icons in a separate `Image` tag. see EDIT 1 of the answer for more help. upvote would be nice

Comment: Throws an error because  it says that **image.icon** is an object. I will try the same example with SVG's and will let you know.

Comment: @squeekyDave could you provide the icons in a zip for implement it on expo and work around?

Comment: I jave updated the code in my question with the icons and how I created them. Hope this will be sufficient.

Comment: @squeekyDave i have just edited the expo snack. Now it works. https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/centered-text

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and patience, this worked perfectly! Wish I could upvote more!

Comment: @squeekyDave is ok hahah i think however that you can upvote every comment LOL